# Why is a BOM appearing on each line of my SASS-compiled CSS?

Tags: css, utf-8, sass

My CSS isn't working, apparently because each line begins with a byte-order mark (BOM).  Chrome's dev console shows each BOM as a red dot, and when I mouse over them it shows `\ufeff`.

[image: Chrome Console]

Why are these BOMs here, and how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BOM can appear if you have any UTF8 content in your file. In particular, Sass will convert entities to the raw UTF8 character in compressed mode, and then add the BOM due to those. Example:

```
/* adds a bullet character to the element */
.blank::before {
    content: "\2022";
}
```

**Solutions:**

- If you are compiling directly with Sass, you can use the `--no-charset` option, which will not add the BOM.
- If you are using `gulp-sass` as I was, it does not support this option. So you can install the [`gulp-stripbom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-stripbom) npm package then add `.pipe(stripBom())` after your Sass compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Your SASS source file is probably messed up.  In my case, the source file somehow wound up with *two* BOMs at the beginning, and SASS (for some reason?) translated this to a BOM at the beginning of every CSS declaration.

[image: Double BOM in broken SASS]

When I remove one of the two BOMs, the compiled CSS comes out clean.

[image: Single BOM in working SASS]

Answer (score 0):

your file is encoding in UTF-8-BOM open your file with notepad++, change encoding to encode in UTF-8, then save it.[encode in UTF-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Laphy.png)